# jQuery: How to get text in a control if value attribute is undefined?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple account number and password form.  I can submit the form in a function that serializes the form and sends it to a Web API controller, and the account number and password are received as properties in a small model I created.  So that works fine.  But I wanted to access the number that the user typed on the page itself, but I cannot figure out how to do it - I tried using var accountNo = $('#account').val() but accountNo is undefined.

All the examples that I have found have the 'value' attribute set in the HTML, wither hardcoded or set using .val('someValue').  But it works to have the user enter the text and then serializing the form, leaving the value attribute empty.  So how do I get the text that the user entered?

I put a sample on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xZVzC/1/

```
<input name="account" type="text" placeholder="Enter Account Number">
```

and

```
$(function() {
  var accountNo = $('#account').val();   
  console.log('Account: ' + accountNo);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you selector is wrong

Change your html have an `id=account` as you are using [# id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) `$('#account').val();` but not having id attribute in your html.

```
<input id="account" name="account" type="text" placeholder="Enter Account Number">
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Pc5RD/)

---

Or

Change Your selector to

```
var accountNo = $('input[name="account"]').val();
```

[`Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Ypu're currently missing `id` of your input so you need to select your input by name:

```
var accountNo = $('input[name="account"]').val();
```

instead of:

```
var accountNo = $('#account').val();
```

or add `id` attribute to your input:

```
<input id= "account" name="account" type="text" placeholder="Enter Account Number">
```

Also you can use **[change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event to keep track when your input value has been changed:

```
$('input[name="account"]').change(function() {
    var accountNo = $(this).val();
    console.log('Account: ' + accountNo);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZVzC/3/)**

or using **[keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)** event when user finish enter any character inside your input:

```
$('input[name="account"]').keyup(function() {
    var accountNo = $(this).val();
    console.log('Account: ' + accountNo);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xZVzC/4/)**

Comment: That's interesting about the change() and keyup() events.  Obviously, I'm not a jQuery expert, this is helpful.  I was following an example from the Microsoft site using Web API and the input controls did not have an id field, just the name, and it worked automagically.  In retrospect, this should have been obvious to me!

Answer (score 0):

You dont have an ID on that field, use the attribute selector:

```
var accountNo = $('input:text[name=account]').val();
```